# Tensorflow transformations for frame sliding (numpy stride_tricks)

Tags: reshape, tensorflow

My input in a tensorflow graph comes as a vector which contains multiple overlapping windows. How can I create this array using only tensorflow operations?

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
shift = 2
window_width = 4
count = (len(input) - window_width) // 2 + 1 = 3

output = [[1,2,3,4],
          [3,4,5,6],
          [5,6,7,8]]
```

In numpy I would use stride_tricks, but something similar isn't available in tensorflow. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 4):

TensorFlow doesn't have stride_tricks. The following would work for your particular use case.

```
>>> b=tf.concat(0, [tf.reshape(input[i:i+4], [1, window_width]) for i in range(0, len(input) - window_width + 1, shift)])
>>> with tf.Session(""): b.eval()
... 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

If your input is large, you may also want to look at [slice_input_producer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#slice_input_producer).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not completely with tf operations. My input is already a tensor (read from a TfRecords file). The len(input) in my example would actually be a tf variable as well.

Comment: @PeterSmit I agree. Did you solve it Peter ? I'm also stuck in a similar case.

Comment: @PeterSmit The problem is in "range" operation not "len", because it can be replaced by tf.shape(input)[0]

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody still needs this, there is a function [tf.signal.frame()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/frame).

For the example given in the question, the code would be:

```
output = tf.signal.frame(input, window_width, shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.map_fn() to accomplish this:

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
shift = 2
window_width = 4
limit = len(input) - window_width + 1

input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(8,))
output_tensor = tf.map_fn(lambda i: input_tensor[i:i+window_width], elems=tf.range(start=0, limit=limit, delta=shift))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    answer_test = sess.run(output_tensor, feed_dict = {input_tensor:input})
    print(answer_test)

:    [[1 2 3 4]
     [3 4 5 6]
     [5 6 7 8]]
```